# pygmo, how to return no value in problem function

Tags: python, optimization, black-box, pygmo

I am using `PyGMO` in Python. I want to find minimum of black box function which could have no value for particular guess. How should i define return value of fitness function if my function does not return value?

Should it be `None` or `float("inf")`? I have tried to return `float("inf")` but it looks like algorithm `PSO_GEN` cannot converge.

Comment: Welcome ! your question is not clear. Are you implementing https://esa.github.io/pygmo/documentation/algorithms.html?highlight=pso_gen#PyGMO.algorithm.pso_gen ??

Comment: Yes that's algoritm i use